# Data Extension fields from ROWS, not COLUMNS, and displaying through AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to build the data extension as per my image below
[image: DataExtension]

And then through AMPscript displaying the values from the rows for each individual email (Email 1, Email 2)?

Example being I want to change Content 2 in Email 2 and Email 4, then I just replace it in the data extension and upload the new file.

Reason why I ask is that when creating the data extension in ET, it ask you for the FIELDS, and these it reads from the columns, and not rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could do something like this:

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount
var @websiteName
set @websiteName = "Email 1" /* literal value */
set @websiteName = AttributeValue("Email 1 ") /* or value from attribute or DE column in send context */

set @rows = LookupRows("EmailContentDataExtension","Website Name", @websiteName)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  var @shortURL, @URL, @Content1
  set @row = row(@rows,1) /* get row #1 */
  set @URL = field(@row,"URL")  
  set @shortURL = field(@row,"shortURL")
  set @Content1 = field(@row,"Content1")

]%%

<br>URL: <a href="%%=redirectto(@URL)=%%">%%=v(@URL)=%%</a> 
<br>shortURL: <a href="%%=redirectto(@shortURL)=%%">%%=v(@shortURL)=%%</a> 
<br>Content1: %%=treatascontent(@Content1)=%%

%%[ else ]%%

No content found for %%=v(@websiteName)=%%

%%[ endif ]%%
```